# Interface problem (Sticky windows)

Tags: interface

The following interface problem occurs,

The UV Image window is attached to the Properties window, if I make the Properties or the UV Image window larger or smaller, the UV Image or Properties window will go along (see photos).

Blender interface-01.jpg - Blender interface-02.jpg

How can I solve this ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if the windows are at the exact same level they will stick to each other, I don't know if there's any other way to solve it than to create a new window and collapse it, like that:

[image]

You could join the areas but I doubt it makes it faster as you'll need to create a new window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works fine again !