# How to unglue the interface areas corners from the intersections?

Tags: interface

I am aware of the banality of this question. But sometimes I find myself in this slightly annoying situation.
When the areas coincide perfectly, they automatically anchor at the intersection. Obviously in the video I show that you can do the trick by creating a new one and sliding the one of the 3d viewport at the bottom. So ok.
But is there any hotkey to unpick this?
[image]

Comment: More than related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/216004/78972